# $not using in Aggregation Framework (mongodb)

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Basicly I would like get items that not start with "3D@ " letters. I am doing aggregation because some items text field repating. I need to take just one.

Collection like that

```
{
   Message:{
   Text: "3d@ asd....",
   .................
   },
   Message:{
   Text: "3d@ asd....",
   .................
   },
   Message:{
   Text: "asd....",
   .................
   },
   Message:{
   Text: "dfg....",
   .................
   },
   Message:{
   Text: "3d@ asd2....",
   .................
   },
   Message:{
   Text: "3d@ asd3....",
   .................
   }
}
```

Query like that

```
db.messages.aggreagation(
{ "$match" : { "Message.Text" : { "$not" : "/^3d\\@" } } },
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "Message.Text" } }
);
```

I am getting that error

Command 'aggregate' failed: exception: bad query: BadValue $not needs a regex or a document (response: { "errmsg" : "exception: bad query: BadValue $not needs a regex or a document", "code" : 16810, "ok" : 0.0 })

What is my misate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error message says, the `$not` value needs to be a regex, not a string:

```js
db.messages.aggreagation(
    { "$match" : { "Message.Text" : { "$not" : /^3d@/ } } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "Message.Text" } }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mongo: PCRE Regex

Use this regex:

```
^(?i)(?!3D@)
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(?i)` turns on case-insensitivity mode
- The negative lookahead `(?!3D@)` asserts that what follows is not `3D@`

Comment: very nice ! Where can I find a complete list of regex?

Comment: `a complete list of regex` You mean regex tutorials? I'd start with rexegg.com, regular-expressions.info or the SO FAQ (see url at the top of the regex tag) Books: Friedl, Goyvaerts